# How to output message when 2 buttons have been pressed consecutively

Tags: javascript, html

Hi im new to javascript and messing about with it.
How can i (if possible) show an output when 2 buttons have been pressed one after the other?

Example: click button 1, click button 2, message shows "button 1 and 2 has been clicked"

Comment: Make a variable ie `clicked` and add 1 when you click either button. On click check if `clicked` is `2` if it is then show message and reset to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

use an `&&` operator in an `if` statement.

Javascript:

```
var button1 = false;
var button2 = false;
var b1_id = document.getElementById('button1');
var b2_id = document.getElementById('button2');
b1_id.addEventListener('click',click1,false);
function click1() {
    alert("Button1 clicked");
    button1 = true;
    check();
}
b2_id.addEventListener('click',click2,false);
function click2() {
    alert("Button2 clicked");
    if (button1 !== false) button2 = true; //this is to make sure they are clicked consecutivley
    check();
}
function check() {
    if (button1 === true && button2 === true) {
        alert("Button1 and Button2 clicked consecutively");
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type='button' id='button1' value='button1' />
<input type='button' id='button2' value='button2' />
```

​[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HYSgy/1/)

Comment: hi somekid thanks for the help this is what i was after. one thing tho. how would i reset the whole situation after ok button is pressed on the message. at the moment you press the two buttons and the message appears then you only need to press one button to get the message again. Thanks David

Comment: add `button1 = false; button2 = false` in the `if` block of the `check` function. I updated the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="status"></p>
<button id="btn1" onclick="clickfun(this);">button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="clickfun(this);">button 2</button>


<script>
clickfun(elm){
var currenthtml = document.getElementById('status').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = currenthtml += this.id+' clicked !';

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually just wrote a library devoted to the mouse object. One thing it does it tracking what buttons are pressed, and follows DOM3 spec mostly.

https://github.com/Benvie/Mouse

Boiled down to minimum, you must continually track the muse to now if the browser does not provide the "buttons" property, which only Firefox 15 does so far. Specially, mousedown to start, then click and contextmenu to end.

The key bits for tracking buttons are

```
var buttons = 0;

function down(e){ buttons |= 1 << e.button; }
function up(e){ buttons &= ~(1 << e.button); }

window.addEventListener('click', up);
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', up);
window.addEventListener('mousedown', down);
```

Comment: Oh I misinterpreted the question to be about the mouse buttons, left and right. Oops.